# Is Google play Real-time developer notifications free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-console

I'm having a hard time understanding about Google play Real-time developer pricing, It requires Google pub/sub topic which I think its not free. So I want to know if I use Google play Real-time developer with Google pub/sub, I have to pay for notifications? If I have, What are the alternatives?

I've read the pricing model of pub/sub and Google play docs but I couldn't find any anwsers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Google Play Real-time developer notifications (free) use Pub/Sub (not free) to deliver notifications. There are no other free options. The pricing for Pub/Sub is so small that you would need a lot of notifications to spend even ten cents.